# spyder kernel error: an error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: tensorflow, kernel, spyder

I bought a new computer and installed windows 11. I installed it on my computer by following the Windows Native part on the Tensorflow site step by step. I verified the GPU setup and it returned me this:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

So as far as I understand, the installation seemed to be successful. When I wanted to train a working model that I wrote on my old computer, after training for about 15 minutes, it gave a message that "kernel is dead". If I didn't turn spyder off and on, I couldn't run my code again. I have repeatedly uninstalled and installed from my computer, tried different ways, but got the same result in all of them. I've been trying to fix it for 3 days but I haven't made any progress. Please help me.

The last time I installed and tried the lower version of anaconda, again after training the model for a while, this is the error I got:

```
2023 18:28:56.450212: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance‑critical operations: AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023 18:28:57.006390: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1641 MB memory: ‑> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2023 18:30:35.689718: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1614] TensorFloat will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
```

Comment: Which tensorflow version have you installed in your system? TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows and anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native. Please refer to this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for more detail and verify if you have followed all the instructed steps properly to install tensorflow with GPU setup.

Comment: Install Tensorflow following official guide:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=en#windows-native